# Text is not visible when setmovementmethod is called on a textview with singleline is true

Tags: android, textview

I have this textView in my app for which `singleLine` is set as `true`.

When I call `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())` on it and set some arabic or urdu text, the text is not visible. Although the textview is visible(i have checked by applying color on its background.

I tried using `maxlines=1` instead of single line which fixes visibility problem, but my text being very long, the text in textview becomes scrollable instead of being ellipsized.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to make text ellipsized instead of scrolling in case of `maxlines=1`?

Appreciate any help.

Edit 1. Adding Sample code:

**JAVA**

```
package com.example.invisibletextsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        String mString = "9876543210 دمية النص";
        mTextView.setText(mString);
        Linkify.addLinks(mTextView, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
        mTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.invisibletextsample.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is it partially visible for a line and you cann't  see rest of the line

Comment: @PankajNimgade added the code. When I run it, only TextView background is visible with no text.

Answer (score 3):

you restrict Maximum line a `TextView` can take when you constraint it with

```
singleLine = "true" ==> text should be only on line long
```

or

`maxlines ="1"  ==> maximum lines taken by TextView should be only 1 line`

remove this lines from xml and your text should appear just fine. and trying putting your `textview` under a `ScrollView` that you may scroll it if test is really huge

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same problem.

So I don't need **setMovementMethod**

Expansion TextView，take over MovementMethod.

```
public class EllipsizeSpannableTextView extends TextView {

private Spannable spannable;

public EllipsizeSpannableTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public EllipsizeSpannableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public EllipsizeSpannableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    super.setText(text, type);
    if (text instanceof Spannable) {
        spannable = (Spannable) text;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (spannable == null) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    int action = event.getAction();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        x -= getTotalPaddingLeft();
        y -= getTotalPaddingTop();

        x += getScrollX();
        y += getScrollY();

        Layout layout = getLayout();
        int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
        int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

        ClickableSpan[] links = spannable.getSpans(off, off, ClickableSpan.class);

        if (links.length != 0) {
            ClickableSpan link = links[0];
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                link.onClick(this);
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Selection.setSelection(spannable, spannable.getSpanStart(link),
                    spannable.getSpanEnd(link));
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            Selection.removeSelection(spannable);
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

add property `android:scrollBars`. try it.

```
android:maxLines="3"
android:scrollBars="vertical"
```

Comment: Actually I want my text to be single-line and ellipsis. I don't need scrolling behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, I think the LinkMovementMethod is conflict with singleLine. If you set LinkMovementMethod and singleLine=true for a textview at same time, the text will not display until you touch it.

finally, I use a hacky way. set another textview under the target textview, set singleLine=true, display same text, but don't setMovementMethod. set onTouchListener for target textview, after touch it, the target textview text will display, then hide this textview.

sample codes:

**xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_content_hacky"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="TestContent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="TestContent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
    tvContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    tvContent.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            tvContentHacky.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }
    });
```